# Element of a screen still found by getByTestID after navigating on another screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I hope I am not spamming too much... Actually, I deleted my previous questions to make this one and keep it small and up to the point.

I have a react native application built with expo with a Home screen with one button. Using a stack navigator, this button can enable users to access Screen1. I want to test the following scenario, using jest and @testing-library/react-native :

When the user clicks on the "go to screen1" button, he is sent to Screen1.

So I did this :

```js
it(
  'should take user to Screen1 when go-to-screen1 button is pressed',
  async () => {
    const navigate = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(<HomeScreen navigation={{ navigate }} />);
    fireEvent.press(getByTestId('go-to-screen1-btn'));
    waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId('screen1')).toBeTruthy());
  },
);
```

This test succeeds.

But this one succeeds also :

```js
it(
  'should take user to Screen1 when go-to-screen1 button is pressed',
  async () => {
    const navigate = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(<HomeScreen navigation={{ navigate }} />);
    fireEvent.press(getByTestId('go-to-screen1-btn'));
    waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId('go-to-screen1-btn')).toBeTruthy());
  },
);
```

Like if the elements on the first page still exists whereas we have moved on another page...

The waitFor is in order to wait for the page change, I tried to remove it but the first test fails if it is removed.

Here is a [github repo with the code I describe](https://github.com/ThibaudFournes77/test-navigation).

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added a link to a github repo to reproduce the issue